# the operation could not be completed. (OSStatus error - 9800.) in SKPSMTPMessage iPhone 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sendmail

I'm trying to send mail from iPhone to any mail, I used SKPSMTPMessage and it works ok with me in all types of emulators
(iPhone/iPad 4.3, iPhone/iPad 5.1, iPhone/iPad 6.0).
But when I try to send from (iPhone/iPad 5.0) it gives me the following Error in dialog

```
 the operation could not be completed. (OSStatus error - 9800.)
```

Any help in this issue?

Comment: Did you get soulution of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Find file `SKPSMTPMessage.m` in your project, and modify the source like `CFDictionarySetValue` & following, it works-

```
//CFDictionarySetValue(sslOptions, kCFStreamSSLLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1);
 CFDictionarySetValue(sslOptions, kCFStreamSSLLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelSSLv3);
```

It seems there are some compatability issues with iOS 5+ or later and this smtp app because iOS started using TLS 1.2.

See:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2287/_index.html